# Android 13 Notification permission dialog apears on top of the splash screen

Tags: android, notifications, android-13

[here shows notification is dialog is opens on splash screen where I want to shows automactially and had a bad flow for user[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOMHG.png)ere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2YJj.png)

I added only notification permission and it shows always when user opens app for the first time.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your main activity (not in Splash Activity) to take permission.
`@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)

```
private fun getNotificationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        Log.e("TAG33", "getNotificationPermission: ", )
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        )
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, below might be the issue you're facing. As a workaround, you can create your notification channel in your main activity.

> If your app targets 12L (API level 32) or lower, the system shows the permission dialog the first time your app starts an activity after you create a notification channel, or when your app starts an activity and then creates its first notification channel. This is usually on app startup.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission